# Did I enable structures?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I've been playing in my Minecraft world (XBox One edition) for a couple of weeks now, and I've not found a village, stronghold, or abandoned mineshaft yet.

Yesterday, I explored (above ground, anyway) an entire map's worth of the world, and still couldn't find a village.

I'm now concerned that (somehow) I didn't enable structures when I initially generated the world, and that there *aren't* any villages, etc.. Is there any way to check?

Comment: Strongholds are underground, abandoned mineshaft too. So the only thing you'd find above ground is villages (or that's the way in pc-minecraft anyway)

Comment: Granted. I didn't find any mineshafts (and usually I would have done within a couple of weeks of play), so I went looking for villages (because above ground is quicker). I haven't found any...

Comment: I thought there was no way to check for World details in Xbox One & 360 and PE

Comment: I found some forum posts that imply that ravines are "structures", but nothing definitive. Is this true for the Console edition? I have a couple of ravines near my house.

Comment: No, they're generated in a similar way but not considered structures for the purpose of the toggle (on PC at least; and I didn't see any mention of it being different on console on the wiki).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't appear to be possible to examine the properties of an existing console saved game, so you'll have to do something like this:

Start the game in *Creative* mode and fly around until you find a generated structure. Make a note of the coordinates. Try to find a few different structures.

Enabling *Creative* mode disables achievements, so you can either make a copy of the game file first, or use the same seed to generate a new world.

You might have to travel a long way before you find any villages. On my world, the only village I could find was about 4 "maps" away.

Then reload your *Survival* game and travel to those coordinates. The structure should be there.

*(Of course, when I started heading to the coordinates of the village that I discovered, I stumbled across an Ocean monument in the sea just a short distance from my home...)*